# All in question

Tags: texas-hold-em

My table had a question about all in.

Player A has a remaining bank roll of $100 and Player B has $50 remaining.  It is player A's bet, and he says "all in" and pushes his chips into the middle.  It is the river, and no bets have been made this round.

Player B only has $50, and says "all in" as well.

Player B ends up winning, does he win Player A's whole $100 or only $50?

Thank you,
Best,
Seth

Answer (score 4):

You can never win more from a given player than you bet.  Neither can you win more from them than they bet.

Player B bet $50 and only had $50 at risk, and so can only win $50 from B.   Player B is technically "all in for less" and the dealer will sometimes call it as such to make it clear that Player B didn't call the whole amount.

If there was a Player C also in the pot for at least $50 and Player B still won, she would also win $50 from Player C.  In that case, supposing Player C had $100 in the pot, then whoever had the better hand between Player C and Player A would win the remaining $50.